# How to get the number of characters in a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple in python:

```
tuple=(“aaa”,”aabc”,”aaara”,”aabsdaaa”)
```

I want to code a function that get the number of a character in tuple:

```
Function((“aaammm”,”aabbcc”,”aaaera”,”aabbaaa”),”a”)
“Character “a” occurred maximum 5 times”
```

I worte a code but it doesnt seem to work right..would you help?

```
def function(tuple,character):
    count=0
    for ch in tuple:
        if(ch==character):
           count+=1
    return count


print("the",character,"occured:",function(tuple,character),"times")
```

Comment: Start by writing some code.

Comment: post some codes that you tried

Comment: SO isn't a free coding site, please go through : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also, try googling your questions and trying them out yourself, before you feel like you really need a hand.

Comment: To count the number of occurrences of a string: `'aabacaa'.count('a')`. You get 5.

Comment: Please do not call your variable `tuple`; you shadow the built-in type of the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.count#str.count) to count the characters and [max](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#max) to get the maximum:

```
def max_count(strings, substr):
    return max(s.count(substr) for s in strings)

all_strings = ("aaammm", "aabbcc", "aaaera", "aabbaaa")
char = "a"
print("Character \"%s\" occurred maximum %d times" %
      (char, max_count(all_strings, char)))
```